# tracking java classes that are called in log

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on a project that is already created by some one. I want to know from which class the guacamole is used. For that purpose I want to know all the classes that are being used during login. So I need to check in log the name of classes that are being called. Is there any way to print the names of all classes. If I try logger.debug then it would take a lot of time and I may miss some of the java classes. I just want to print the name of java classes not any specific message/text.

Comment: Firstly did you run your application on debug mode?

Comment: yes, I am running in debug mode, but it is not showing names of all classes being called.

Comment: you could add the name of the class to the debug message such as this `logger.debug(ourClass.class.getName() + "msg")`

Comment: thanks Nagarz, It would require me to write this in almost 30000 files and I can not edit .class files. Is there any other way?

Comment: Use something like aspectj.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Aspect Oriented Programming here. Using AspectJ you will be able to log all the points in the flow of login.

For example, using the AspectJ compiler (which can be integrated to Eclipse, Emacs and others IDEs). Below is a sample of code which will log method entry/exit for all methods inside package `aspects.trace.demo`

```
aspect AspectExample {
    before() : execution(* aspects.trace.demo.*.*(..))
    {
         logger.entering(thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getName(), thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getDeclaringType()   );

    }

    after() : execution(* aspects.trace.demo.*.*(..))
    {
         logger.exiting(thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getName() , thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getDeclaringType()  );

    }
}
```

Below is the link for @AspectJ cheat sheet
http://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/20/aspectj-cheat-sheet/